# How to add class on Widget Title

Tags: widgets

This is an example of register sidebar function from codex. My focus is on the `before_title` argument. What i want is to add a class to the title(`<h3>`). From my widget code or may be pass the class name from user input on widget area.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'name'          => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-$i',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>' ); 

register_sidebar( $args );

?>
```

So, **How do i add classes dynamically on widget header?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. **Don't bother**

   Just target `.widget.{dynamic-class} h3` instead
2. **Use `%2$s`**

   I don't know if this will work, but try:

   `'before_title' => '<h3 class="%2$s">'`

But personally, I'd go with the former option. You've already got a unique class name; just leverage the element hierarchy to apply styles selectively.

Comment: The class name is parsed into `'before_widget'` only.