# How to change the default class for the widget title?

Tags: widgets, css

I would like to change the default class of the widget title. Currently it is h2 and I would like it to be h3. I have seen there is the option of customizing css so that h2 looks like h3.

```
#sidebar h2 {
font-size: 24px;
}
```

But then, this may cause a problem if I modify h3 later, h2 will not follow the changes.

And I also saw this discussion [How to add class on Widget Title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55555/how-to-add-class-on-widget-title) about how to create a register a new widget.

But I would like to apply it to the default widget, not register a new one...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

`h2` and `h3` are not html *classes*, they are [html *tags*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp).

That said, does not exists a default html tag for the widgets, because the format used to output widgets title is set [when the sidebar is registered](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) (look at 'before_title' argument).

So how title is shown is **theme related and sidebar related**, does not depends on widgets.

An easy way to change the html tag your theme is using for widget titles, is to use the `'dynamic_sidebar_before'` hook (fired just before the sidebar is shown) and global `$wp_registered_sidebars` variable to alter the 'before_title' argument on the sidebar being shown, thanks to the fact the hook pass the sidebar id:

```
add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar_before', 'widget_title_h2_h3' );

function widget_title_h2_h3( $sidebar_id ) {
 global $wp_registered_sidebars;
 if ( isset( $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id] ) ) {
    if ( isset($wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['before_title']) ) {
      $now = $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['before_title'];
      $h3 = str_ireplace( '<h2', '<h3', $now );
      $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['before_title'] = $h3;
    }
 }
}
```

However this will change h2 to h3 in all your sidebars (at least all the sidebars where there is an h2 in the widget title).

To apply code to a specific sidebar, add a condition inside outer `if` that should appear like so:

```
if ( $sidebar_id === 'sidebar-id' && isset( $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id] ) ) {
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer is really clarifying. I would vote you, but unfortunately I cannot since I don't have 15 points of reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

By default the WordPress sidebars use H2 tags. To change these to use H3 tags instead, add this to your functions.php file:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
 register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Sidebar','before_title'=>'<h3>','after_title'=>'</h3>'));
```